# SQL Server throwing error in SQL for Odd / Even check

Tags: sql-server, floating-point, syntax-error

I have a SQL Server database that is throwing an error on one of my tables when I add a check for an even or odd number value.

Here is an example script which would cause the error:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM [TABLE_QUALIFIER].[TABLE_OWNER].[TABLE_NAME] WITH (nolock) 
WHERE street_number BETWEEN '1' AND '5000' 
  AND (street_number % 2) > 0 
  AND street_name LIKE '%Main St%' 
ORDER BY CAST(street_number AS float);
```

As you can see, I have this piece of the statement checking for odd results:

```
AND (street_number % 2) > 0
```

If I eliminate this bit of the call, I get a successful query result. However, in this case I need to include the check of odd street number results.

When I check the table info with this command:

```
exec sp_columns [TABLE_NAME];
```

I can see that the `street_number` column is saved as a `varchar` type. In the SQL statement, you can see that I am casting the `street_number` value as a float.

Any suggestions on how I can amend this SQL query to remove the error when checking for an odd `street_number`?

Additional info:

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU19) (KB4535007) - 14.0.3281.6 (X64) Jan 23 2020 21:00:04 Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Are you sure the values are numbers in the column since it is declared as varchar?  Try selecting the data and find anything for that column that is not a number.  Also I dont see your error message you are getting?

Comment: Have you done an WHERE ISNUMERIC(street_number) = 0  to check wich values are causing the problem?

Comment: @Brad the error that I get is simply "Error in SQL."  The results for the column are the street number of 131.

Comment: @Joaquín `ISNUMERIC` is far from a great function. `TRY_CONVERT`/`TRY_CAST` are infinitely better options.

Comment: @Joaquín I have just added the `WHERE ISNUMERIC(street_number) = 0` check and it gave no results.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: @codacopia, #1 out of ##1-4 is till missing, please provide.

Comment: There is no short-circuiting in tsql. You cannot assume that isnumeric is validated first followed by all the other conditions that require a numeric value in order to work correcctly. And really - addresses have no standards. Street numbers often contain characters that are not numerals. Multi-family units, apartments, office buildings, PO boxes. You assume far too much.

Comment: And [stop splattering your code with nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a conceptual example for you. It includes DDL and sample data population.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, street_number VARCHAR(10), street_name VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @tbl (street_number, street_name) VALUES
('1', 'Main St.'),
('10', 'Not so Main St.'),
('20', 'Wall St.'),
('10A', 'Wall St.');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT ID, street_name
        , TRY_CAST(street_number AS INT) AS street_no
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT TOP(5) * 
FROM rs
WHERE street_no BETWEEN 1 AND 5000
  AND (street_no % 2) > 0 
  AND street_name LIKE '%Main St%' 
ORDER BY street_no;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------------+-----------+
| ID | street_name | street_no |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | Main St.    |         1 |
+----+-------------+-----------+
```